# Java lesson: public void displayMessage() Doesn't working

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java book and im trying to learn obviously Java Programming.

I have a lesson that tells me simply to put this Code on Eclipse.

I copied from the Book and i put it on Eclipse program that i test and learn there. When i run it, it doesn't says any error. But at the moment that i run it, it shows me this error:

[Code on Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw2Va.jpg)

[Code on the Book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQZcv.jpg)

Does anyone knows what happens here? Is the book wrong or what?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't attach screen shots, instead paste the code in your question.

Comment: Does the book say that you can run this code? If it does, then yes, it's wrong. Otherwise, it's just that you think you can run this code directly, but you can't. This code is supposed to be called from somewhere else (ultimately from a main method).

Comment: your class method looks ok, you are missing the main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **public** class GradeBook and you have not defined the main[String args[]] method inside it. (*Remember JVM expects main method inside the public class, if JVM not found the main method then it complains for that.*)

if you just want to compile your code successfully without run time target simply remove the **public** before class.

Or

Define the main method inside your public class GradeBook

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write the main method as suggested by the compiler here. When you run a Java Program, the JVm searches for the main method in the class. There is no main method defined in this case, so it is giving this error.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 new GradeBook().displayMessage();
}
```

Add the above code snippet to your class and run it. It will work.
To learn more about main method in Java check this link
[Java Main Method](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/main-method.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `main` method to your `class` and call `displayMessage()` in it :

```
class GradeBook {

    public void displayMessage() {
        System.out.println("something");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GradeBook().displayMessage();
    }
}
```